# Display a Wordpress article under a category in a page

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I am working on wordpress with my own theme:

I have a page called Exhibition, on this page I have two categories: 'Currently' and 'Preview'.

When I post an article, I would like to choose one of the categories where the title (the permalink) of the post will be displayed. The categories are not buttons, they are just 'title' where the different posts come under.

I made a template file called exhibition.php (see code below), which is applied to my Exhibition page in Wordpress. I don't know how to call the function to display the category name, and then to attribute the category to my post to finally display it one the page.

I add an image to picture what I am writting.

If someone know how to build that function, some help will be very appreciated!

Thanks

[image]

**exhibition.php**

```
<div class="container">
<?php $cat_1_args = array("cat" => $cat_1_id);
  $cat_1_query = new WP_Query($cat_1_args);?>
  <?php if($cat_1_query->have_posts()): ?>
     <h1><?php get_cat_name($cat_1_id);?>
     <?php while($cat_1_query->have_posts()):?>
         <?php $cat_1_query->the_post();?>
         <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php $first = str_replace(' | ', '<br />', get_the_title()); echo str_replace('REPLACE_ME', '<i>REPLACE_ME</i>', $first);?></a>
<?php endwhile;?>
</div> 

<?php endif; ?>
```

**HTML output result**

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1> <a href="http://temporarygallery.org/do-not-remove-this-folder/nouvelle-exposition-2/">BOOK LAUNCH &#038; KÜNSTLERGESPRÄCH</a>
    <a href="http://temporarygallery.org/do-not-remove-this-folder/alleinanspruch/">PARKFIELD STUDIES<br />Marianna Christofides<br /><i>27 August – 30 August 2017</i></a>
    <a href="http://temporarygallery.org/do-not-remove-this-folder/second-post-test/">RESPAWN<br />Eloïse Bonneviot, Anne de Boer<br /><i>4 July – 30 July 2017</i></a>
    <a href="http://temporarygallery.org/do-not-remove-this-folder/third-post-test/">THE COMMON TOAD<br />Victoria Adam<br /><i>27 Mai – 30 Juli 2017</i></a>
    <a href="http://temporarygallery.org/do-not-remove-this-folder/fourth-post-test/">ALLEINANSPRUCH<br />Arne Schmitt, Nico Joana Weber<br /><i>4 Februar – 30 April 2017</i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Lolo - StackOverflow is not a "write this for me" code service.  We are volunteer developers helping other developers _with specific problems_.  You need to show us what you've tried, and what is / is not working about it, and then we can help you solve that problem.

Comment: @cale_b, you're right, sorry! Forgot to post what I have tried to start. The issue is that I really don't know how to get further than that…

Comment: Ok, let's see if I have this right: you have two categories of post and want to display *in the same page* the posts of category one under the title "category one" and the posts of category two under the title "category two", right?

Comment: @frollo , that is absolutely right! (detail: I want to display the permalink of the post (it is its title), that will open the post's content in a single page)

Answer (score 0):

To get the category name you need to use [`get_cat_name($cat_id)`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_cat_name). Note that you already need `$cat_id` to get all the posts in a single category. I'd also split everything in two query (and two loops), one per category. It should look something like this:

```
<?php $cat_1_args = array("cat" => $cat_1_id);
  $cat_1_query = new WP_Query($cat_1_args);?>
<?php if($cat_1_query->have_posts()): ?>
     <h1><?php get_cat_name($cat_1_id);?></h1>
     <?php while($cat_1_query->have_posts()):?>
         <?php $cat_1_query->the_post();?>
         <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php $first = str_replace(' | ', '<br />', get_the_title()); echo str_replace('REPLACE_ME', '<i>REPLACE_ME</i>', $first);?></a>
     <?php endwhile;?>
```

And then do the same thing for the second category.

Comment: thank you for that! I have updated my question (see code), but I am still not sure if it is written correctly. Now the page is showing a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' on this line : <?php if($cat_1_query->have_posts): ?> –

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I updated the answer fixing my code, now it should work

Comment: thank you. There are no error anymore. But now it is showing up all my posts links. How can display the category name on the page and the attributed posts in this category. I have updated my code.

Comment: can you please post an example of the HTML output? I'm a bit rusty in Wordpress, but maybe if I read the output I'd understand better what's going on

Comment: I added the html output result in my post. But I am not working on any html file, I am only working on the exhibition.php

Comment: Ok, my best guess (beside the fact that I forgot to close the `h1` tag) is that the `get_cat_name($cat_1_id)` is not printing anything. Try by `echo`ing its output and check what's inside `$cat_1_id` (I'd say it's correct because the posts are found, but it's better to be certain).

Comment: I understand your point, but I am not sure to understand how to do that. I am really a beginner in php. Where is the output of get_cat_name($cat_1_id) and how do I echo it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153266/discussion-between-frollo-and-lolo).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to re-build the wheel here.

There is a plugin that does exactly what you're looking to achieve called: [List category posts](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/list-category-posts/)

No need to create a custom template for your page, just put the shortcode provided by the plugin (with the right attributes) when you just need some CSS to customize the rendering to match your theme (you can even customize the template I believe).